# How to Import Products, Categories and Custom Attributes from database?

Tags: database, magento2.2, import

As the question says.

I want to import `products`, `categories` and custom `attributes` on database level. What tables do I need to take with me?

**For the curious among you:**

The reason is that I had a server that has been corrupted that used to host my website. Now all what I'm left with is a `.sql` file from a backup that contains all my products data.
I also have an export of products from Magento admin in a `.csv` file. But I realized the hard way that **Magento 2 default import/export is a total crap**.

Answer (score 2):

Magento 2:

**Export Attribute tables:-**

```
eav_attribute
catalog_eav_attribute
eav_attribute_group
eav_attribute_label
eav_attribute_option
eav_attribute_option_swatch
eav_attribute_option_value
eav_attribute_set
eav_entity
eav_entity_attribute
eav_entity_datetime
eav_entity_decimal
eav_entity_int
eav_entity_store
eav_entity_text
eav_entity_type
eav_entity_varchar
eav_form_element
eav_form_fieldset
eav_form_fieldset_label
eav_form_type
eav_form_type_entity
```

**Export Product tables:-**

```
`cataloginventory_stock_item`
`cataloginventory_stock_status`
`cataloginventory_stock_status_idx`
`cataloginventory_stock_status_tmp`
`catalog_category_product`
`catalog_category_product_index`
`catalog_category_product_index_tmp`
`catalog_compare_item`
`catalog_product_bundle_option`
`catalog_product_bundle_option_value`
`catalog_product_bundle_price_index`
`catalog_product_bundle_selection`
`catalog_product_bundle_selection_price`
`catalog_product_bundle_stock_index`
`catalog_product_entity`
`catalog_product_entity_datetime`
`catalog_product_entity_decimal`
`catalog_product_entity_gallery`
`catalog_product_entity_int`
`catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`
`catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`
`catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity`
`catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_video`
`catalog_product_entity_text`
`catalog_product_entity_tier_price`
`catalog_product_entity_varchar`
`catalog_product_index_eav`
`catalog_product_index_eav_decimal`
`catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_idx`
`catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_tmp`
`catalog_product_index_eav_idx`
`catalog_product_index_eav_tmp`
`catalog_product_index_price`
`catalog_product_index_price_bundle_idx`
`catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_idx`
`catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_tmp`
`catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_idx`
`catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_tmp`
`catalog_product_index_price_bundle_tmp`
`catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_idx`
`catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_tmp`
`catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_idx`
`catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_tmp`
`catalog_product_index_price_downlod_idx`
`catalog_product_index_price_downlod_tmp`
`catalog_product_index_price_final_idx`
`catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`
`catalog_product_index_price_idx`
`catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_idx`
`catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_tmp`
`catalog_product_index_price_opt_idx`
`catalog_product_index_price_opt_tmp`
`catalog_product_index_price_tmp`
`catalog_product_index_tier_price`
`catalog_product_index_website`
`catalog_product_link`
`catalog_product_link_attribute_decimal`
`catalog_product_link_attribute_int`
`catalog_product_link_attribute_varchar`
`catalog_product_option`
`catalog_product_option_price`
`catalog_product_option_title`
`catalog_product_option_type_price`
`catalog_product_option_type_title`
`catalog_product_option_type_value`
`catalog_product_relation`
`catalog_product_super_attribute`
`catalog_product_super_attribute_label`
`catalog_product_super_link`
`catalog_product_website`
`catalog_url_rewrite_product_category`
`downloadable_link`
`downloadable_link_price`
`downloadable_link_purchased`
`downloadable_link_purchased_item`
`downloadable_link_title`
`downloadable_sample`
`downloadable_sample_title`
`product_alert_price`
`product_alert_stock`
```

Export category tables:-

```
catalog_category_entity
catalog_category_entity_datetime
catalog_category_entity_decimal
catalog_category_entity_int
catalog_category_entity_text
catalog_category_entity_varchar
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I see that my products and categories are there. But whenever I go to the product page in admin, I receive the following error: https://pastebin.com/2SSwZadK

Comment: Are you Importing Attribute using  csv ?

Comment: No, I have imported the tables you have mentioned on a fresh Magento 2 install